# Convert negative color numbers to HEX or RGB

Tags: php, css, sql, oracle, colors

I've never seen color codes like `-1`, `-16777216`, `-256`, etc. So my current problem is this:

We have a third-party software where you can color-code a value as illustrated in the picture below.

[image: software]

Now I'm creating a PHP report that displays those values but I also want to display them using the same colors as what is defined in the software. I was able to hunt the values down from the database but I'm confused as the values are in a format or notation that I'm not familiar with.

[image: database]

How can I convert these values to either HEX or RGB in either Oracle or PHP? PHP is what I'm used to (I will use it for CSS for the report).

#### Edit

Looking at the database and the colors in the software I could at least match the numbers like so:

> `-1` = White
>
> `-12582784` = Purple
>
> `-65408` = Pink
>
> `-16777216` = Black
>
> `-256` = Yellow

#### Additional Edit

So it looks like 16777216 is a perfect cube number. Its cube root is 256 (on RGB each primary color can be represented by a number from 0-255). So far that's the only relationship I can see think of. I still don't know how to convert that to HEX or RGB though.

---

I've done some research although not really fruitful. But I'll include it so I don't look like I didn't make an attempt - if you're not interested in it then just ignore it:

[16777216](http://davidnaylor.org/blog/2005/02/all-16777216-rgb-colours/) - I started by searching the actual code `-16777216` but that didn't return anything so I removed the negative sign.

[Facts about 16777216](http://numbermatics.com/n/16777216/) - that page shows some formulas but I didn't see any that converts to HEX or RGB.

Comment: For the color codes part, there's an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903820/what-values-are-used-as-reference-to-calculate-the-color-code-here

Comment: Thanks @haslam that seems like the perfect match to what I'm experiencing. I'm going to try and understand it for now.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is conversion between signed and unsigned integers. I understand these negative numbers are currently stored in a table; do you know how they were generated?

Comment: @mathguy No I don't. The third-party software is a .NET application so I'm guessing using C# methods?

Comment: If I had to do this manually, just to test the hypothesis of inadvertent conversion to signed int: Add 256^3 to the negative numbers and "write" the result in base 256. The "digits" are (or should be) the RGB code. Clearly this works for black (adding 256^3 results in 0, the correct code for black), and clearly this is correct for yellow (values 255, 255, 0). And for white (you get 255, 255, 255).

Comment: @mathguy I'll take a look at your suggestion tomorrow. But my question is why should I do it that way instead of using PHP's [`dechex`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)?

Comment: If you already found a working solution, you don't need to do anything else. My comment was just in case you are still trying to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your colours are indeed RGB values stored in a slightly twisted way.
All you have to do is, take the decimal number away from 16777216 and convert to HEX.

16777216-1 = 16777215 (FFFFFFh = White)

16777216-12582784 = 4194432 (400080h = Purple)

16777216-65408 = 16711808 (FF0080h = Pink)

16777216-16777216 = 0 (000000h = Black)

16777216-256 = 16776960 (FFFF00h = Yellow)

I hope this helps.
Apologies for not writing a code, but I am afraid I am not quite there yet in my studies. I promise I will work on it when I get there. :)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting solution. I'll take a look at this tomorrow.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio - just making sure you realize this is the same as what I suggested in my Comment.

Comment: So I'm trying to see if this one works but I'm wondering how you got to convert `16776960` to `FFFF00`?

Comment: Sorry I asked too quickly - using PHP's [`dechex`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) I was able to convert those numbers. Thank you and thanks to you too @mathguy!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using PHP to pull the BACK_COLOR (i.e. "coded color reference id") into each table cell. Prefix that negative number with a character for CSS reasons. Include CSS that specifies the color per dynamic class.

```
<style>
.g-1 { color: #000; background: #ffffff /* white */ } 
.g-12582784 { color: #fff; background: #3F0180 /* purple */ } 
.g-65408 { color: #fff; background:  #FF0080 /* pink */ } 
.g-256 background: { color: #000; #FFFD05 /* yellow */ }
.g-16777216 { color: #fff; background: #000000 /* black */ }
</style>

<table>
<tr>
<td class="g-12582784">Option 1</span> <!-- use PHP to generate this class -->
<td class="g-65408">Option 2</span> <!-- use PHP to generate this class -->
<td class="g-256">Option 3</span> <!-- use PHP to generate this class -->
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to avoid hard-coding the colors as the users might decide to change them later on.

Comment: Use PHP to pull in the color code dynamically. You made that awsome dechex function -- use it to write the css color hex.

Comment: It is possible apparently - look at the answer I posted that I found out a couple minutes ago. Seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP I created this function [thanks to this note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php#53325).

```
function toColor($n) {
    return ("#".substr("000000".dechex($n),-6));
}
```

It converts the signed int to hex and it looks like the colors match. On a separate quest I want to reduce the alpha channel down because the colors are very strong but I'll save that for another day.