# How to convert this value(-16777188) into HEX color?

Tags: php, colors, rgb

How can I convert negative value to hexcolor code?

```
$R = $p_nColor & 0xFF;
$G = ($p_nColor >> 8) & 0xFF;
$B = ($p_nColor >> 16) & 0xFF;
echo sprintf("#%02X%02X%02X", $R, $G, $B);
```

i am trying this but it's give me wrong output

Comment: Your lines of code produce a correct result. Only the alpha component is missing. What result do you expect?

Comment: it should be #D7E4F2

Answer (score 0):

you can see the following link to find your answer
[Convert negative color numbers to HEX or RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633608/convert-negative-color-numbers-to-hex-or-rgb)

Comment: If you believe there is an existing question which answers this question, you should post a comment that it is a duplicate.

Comment: function toColor($n) {
    return ("#".substr("000000".dechex($n),-6));
}

This is give me different color code